# Where are TWRP backups stored on SD card? Had to un-root

Tags: twrp

I had to un-root my LG G2 Verizon because recovery got corrupted. I created a TWRP backup some time ago from within its recovery and it was stored on the internal drive. I did a system reset, and then un-rooted by going back to stock image. Did the system reset delete that backup file from my SD card? If not, what location is it under?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flashing the stock image may have erased your backup. However, since the G2 supports an External SD card, I don't think it would have.

From the SD Card's root, it should be at `./TWRP/BACKUPS/`. Restoring a backup from here using TWRP will re-root your device (If your device was rooted when you made the backup). You can also use apps like Titanium Backup to selectively restore parts of it... but Titanium Backup requires root.

You may, however, be able to selectively pull files from the backups - a full backup of your phone's filesystems.

Answer (score 2):

On my LG G2 (Verizon model), the TWRP backup is located in `root/data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/` (folder with a bunch of letters and numbers / folder with date and numbers, etc. *this* is your backup)

Now this is using TWRP version 2.8.6.1

You won't be able to see it by hooking up to your computer. You will need to use a root explorer file manager and then copy that folder (one with the date) to your SD card partition (I put mine in the downloads folder to find it easier) then hook up to your computer and copy it somewhere safe.

Answer (score 1):

Use Droid Explorer to access those system files and folders on PC.

1. Go to [Droid Explorer's Official website](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer)
2. Download the program.
3. Run it and grant USB debugging permission.
4. You can find the TWRP backup under /data/media/0/TWRP/(backups folder)

That's it, take a copy of that and you are safe.

Answer (score 0):

The location depends on what mode is the Android currently running in. When you use `adb` while running recovery, the location is like `/data/media/TWRP` (or `/data/media/0/TWRP`). When you have the system running, the location is `/sdcard/TWRP`.

If you do not want to install Droid Explorer as advised by Hariharan G, you can use `adb` from command line to copy the files:

While running recovery:

```
adb pull /data/media/TWRP/BACKUPS BACKUPS
```

While running normally:

```
adb pull /sdcard/TWRP/BACKUPS BACKUPS
```

(Those are paths I see for backups with TWRP 2.7.1.0 on rooted Motorola Xoom with Android 4.1 and 4.4.4 - TWRP prints the path valid while running in recovery when performing backup, you can check it in the log)