# How to restore nandroid?

Tags: data-recovery, nandroid, twrp

I created a nandroid backup and copied the files to my computer

```
boot.img
cache.ext4.tar
data.ext4.tar
nandroid.md5
recovery.log
system.ext4.log
ta.img
```

I deleted the files on my phone to save space and now have copied them back. I used Online Nandroid Pro and not sure how to actually get it to do a complete restore?

Comment: Did you look at their help info yet? How much did you do already? What part is not making sense? Please provide more information. Did you take a look at the apps XDA forum thread https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.google.com/url?q%3Dhttp://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t%253D1620255%26sa%3DD%26usg%3DAFQjCNHMcZo_vjC3JaITFTS8OvONZo4lng&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNFACj6mROgyufNlWz3qy7Cfks8kFg

Comment: @HasH_BrowN I've tried a lot of things. Can any app restore from a nandroid backup even if it's not the same one that made it, for example can TWRP restore a nandroid made from CWM? Also when I do restore, should I expect to no longer see apps that I've installed since the nandroid was made? I'll take a look at the link.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN my question is how do you use the user interface? I can't see any option inside Online Narndoid to restore and it requries Nandroid Manager to select a recovery. In nanroid manager there is "explore  backup", which lists a bunch of files and "restore data" with some options. So what do I do to get 100% restored from the nandroid?

Comment: You might wish to see: [Restore only part of nandroid image](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/7851/16575) – and, of course, our [nandroid tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/nandroid/info). Will save you from waiting for answers which are already there :)

Comment: @Izzy I want to do the exact opposite: how do you restore ALL of the nandroid image? So that anythings added after the nandroid image will no longer be there.

Answer (score 1):

To restore a [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) [backup](/questions/tagged/backup), the device cannot be in "normal operation mode". You have to boot into your (custom) recovery (see our tag-wikis on: [recovery-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info) / [clockworkmod](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/clockworkmod/info) / [twrp](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/twrp/info)), from where you can trigger a full restore. With *ClockworkMod Recovery*, it is e.g. found in the *Backup & Restore* sub-menu.

Stock recoveries don't offer taking/restoring Nandroid backups. But as you were able to create one, it's pretty safe to assume you've also got a custom recovery installed to your device.

Comment: I do have TWRP and I tried this but it didn't show the nandroid backup, as if it wouldn't find it.

Comment: Have you placed your backups in the right location? See: [Where are TWRP backups stored on SD card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/57842/16575) If so, you might have to ask the TWRP guys for details.

Answer (score 1):

I once extracted single apps and apps data using a normal archiver explorer in my Arch Linux system. In Windows, 7-Zip FM or Winrar should do the trick.

Obviously it is quicker done if you restore the full backup all at once with a custom recovery (but I believe you already merged the archive parts the backup is done in), but I once made a backup after the system launcher went to a systematic crash, so I couldn't do anything, and doing a full restore would led to the very same problematic, so I had to get back the data of the apps I wanted to restore that way.

Just open the `.tar` files, they are compressed archives. `data.tar` contains what the `data` folder contains in your Internal Storage: upon all the folders, `data/app` contains the apk of the applications you have installed, and `data/data` their saved data, which is you may want to restore. Inside that folder, every app has its dedicated folder (e.g., `data/data/com.google.android.apps.maps` for `Google Maps`). Copying it in your `data/data` folder in your phone with a root file manager will restore the data for that app.

Again, for a complete restore, just copy the whole packages (supposing you left them untouched) in the directory they were (to find out which it is, do another backup and you will see where it is created), boot into a custom recovery like CWM Recovery and do a full system restore, pointing to where the backup is located in your phone.